# Client side unable to connect to socket

Tags: python, html, sockets, raspberry-pi

Please stay indulgent I am just starting with sockets and IT is not my field.

I have a RaspberryPi connected to my desktop with an Ethernet cable.
The RPi is used as a web server (apache2 and PHP installed).
From the desktop I can access the default webpage.
So far so good.

I have created a Python script on the RPi that open a socket and send random number through it.

```
import socket
import random
import time


HOST = ''
PORT = 8080

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'


try:
        s.bind((HOST,PORT))
except socket.error:
        print 'Bind failed'


rnd = random.random()
print rnd


s.listen(1)
print 'Socket awaiting messages'
(conn, addr) = s.accept()
print 'Connected to ' + str(addr)


while True:
        rnd = random.random()
        print rnd
        conn.send(str(rnd))
        time.sleep(1)

conn.close()
```

If I execute this script it hangs until a client open a connection.
So, from my desktop I open Firefox and type in the address: "192.168.137.2:8080".

Nothing happens in the Firefox windows except that it seems that the browser is waiting that the "page" is done loading. Anyway from the console on my RPi I can see random numbers displayed. So I assume that in some way the connection has been correctly opened.

Curiously enough when I change the `time.sleep(1)` to `time.sleep(0.01)` I can also see the text displayed in Firefox...
But let's say that it's ok.

Now, if I create a script in Python and execute it from my desktop I can see that both scripts work.

```
import socket

HOST = "192.168.137.2"
PORT = 8080

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
print "Connected"

while True:
    dat = socket.recv(1024)
    print str(dat)

print "Close"
socket.close()
```

So far so good... Not for long.
Now I want to get the values send in the socket with JS from a webpage served by the RPi.
So I created an html file on my RPi

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.137.2:8080/ws");
            console.log("socket created");

            ws.onerror = function(err){  console.log(err);  };
            ws.onopen = function(){  console.log("connection opened");  };
            ws.onmessage = function(e){  console.log(e.data);  };
            ws.onclose = function(){  console.log("connection closed");  };

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I open this page with Firefox from my desktop I obtain this error (translated in English):
Firefox cannot establish connection with the server ath the address ws://192.168.137.2:8080/ws.

And from the RPi the script stop hanging, starts to display few values and then crashes indicating the pipe is broken.

So my question is what did I did wrong in the html file? How do I make it display the values in the console?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "
I have a RaspberryPi connected to my desktop with an Ethernet cable. " That may be your first problem. If you are going to connect two machines like this, and not via a hub, you need a crossover cable, are you using one of these?

Comment: It is working great. I can access my RPi via Putty. And I can communicate through the socket using only Python. I thinks it is safe to say that the RJ45 connection is not blame.

Comment: OK Now we need to get a tool like wireshark and see what firefox is sending.and receiving

Comment: Alslo check the wikipedia article on websocket at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is becasue your server comes with no protocol support!!!

Your python client scripts also has no protocol and just displays anything from server, fair and logical enough to check if connection is working.

but firefox expected a protocol when it calls your server, and it's mostly http. But seems your server doesn't talk http.

simply read http rfc and response your data followed by http. Then both direct url call by firefox, and javascript will work.

Comment: I noticed that typing 192.168.137.2:8080 in my browser address bar makes it work. But obviously this does not load any page nor js to get the values and do something with it...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am very new to this. And I do not understand you are advising to do.

Comment: I try to explain it clear. when FF connect to your server, it expects something he understand such as http. But seems your server doesn't talk http, so you cannot see anything senseful by FF. Your server should talk HTTP, so FF or any browser would understand.

Comment: Just try to read some simple http server coding, this is really easy, you indeed would make it happen, go for it. Ask any issue you face, we help, and this is why we are here. Keep going on great work.